# BOM characters in vi and more commands

Tags: linux, vi, byte-order-mark

I wanted to remove BOM from a file but if use more there are visible but if i use vi to edit they are not visible.Please help to find the way.

> ï»¿0000199494  : more
>
> 0000199494     : vi

```
[root@axydevt1 axwdev]# more /home/axwdev/PO20131203141833_2.txt
ï»¿0000199494      S         201312022013120220131203        PO-1312-00187       YES       SAM0196   èå·ææµ©çµå­æéå
¬å¸(RMB)          0512-66395196, 0512-6639
7152       SM7            RMB8300                    


[root@axydevt1 axwdev]# vi /home/axwdev/PO20131203141833_2.txt
0000199494      S         201312022013120220131203        PO-1312-00187       YES       SAM0196   èå·ææµ©çµå­æéå
7152RMB)   SM7    0512-663RMB83000512-66399                         Costs, insurance & freight         0.170   17% input tax,
```

Comment: Do you have Vim available?

Comment: yes it is available thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Vim, you should be able to just open the file, `:set nobomb`, and write it out again. Alternatively, using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\xef\xbb\xbf//' PO20131203141833_2.txt
```

Comment: Thank you it was useful. Even if we use vim it shows BOM to delete.

Comment: You need to use different files for input and output. Otherwise you're emptying the input file.